# Ошибка с медиазапросами

Tags: html, css

У меня не работают медиазапросы почему то, только начинаю писать и ставлю @ как редактор кода уже мне говорит что происходит ошибка, код даже не подсвечивает адекватно цветами как должно быть когда все правильно, а в браузере в инструментах разработчика отображается ошибка "unknown property name", типа неопознанное название, мета-тег meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" есть если что. Второй медиазапрос вроде уже отображает в редакторе корректно,но ничего все равно не работает, снова выдает ошибку unknown property name.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В css обращение к классам в медиазапросе происходит таким образом

```css
.contaiter {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(214, 13, 13);
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: 0 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .contaiter {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .contaiter {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, все банально оказалось )

Comment: @ElProblema пожалуйста, если мой ответ помог отметьте мой вопрос галочкой (слева от ответа)

Comment: @АлександрСычёв Всё не так однозначно. Ваш вариант требует обертки свойств в класс. Больше похоже, что автор вопроса скопировал SCSS (SASS) код, где допускается оборачивание свойства в медиа-запрос внутри класса, тогда при компиляции он будет вынесен отдельно. При этом он ожидает, что в CSS та же логика.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar возможно и так, но автор вопроса в комментарии выше дал понять, что ошибка в скобке. Если это не так, думаю он сообщит

Comment: @АлександрСычёв Ну скоро задаст вопрос) Медиа-запросы эти же работать сейчас вообще не будут

Comment: Почему? У пользователя синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: да,действительно, в SCSS коде все работало нормально, я только учусь и думал что и в CSS так же все работает,но нет, в CSS как все таки сделать чтобы все работало адекватно? Буду предельно благодарен за обьяснение как надо это записывать в CSS?

Comment: @ElProblema сейчас подправлю ответ для css

Comment: @Александр Сычёв благодарю

Comment: @ElProblema изменил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Александр Сычёв все работает,большая благодарность,а то не знал уже на что грешить, уже думал Винду переустанавливать даже,думал что то сломалось,ведь в SCSS все работало ведь ))) Еще раз большая благодарность.

Comment: @ElProblema рад был помочь ))) такие кардинальные вещи как "переустановить винду" точно не следует делать в таких случаях ))). Если что-то не понятно погуглите, если не найдете решения пишите сюда